# Loop through categories recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I'm building a python function which returns an array to be used in a select dropdown field. I have tried two versions so far.

Both of them work, with the first returning a properly formatted select field. However, the first solution only goes two levels deep. I intend to add more depth to the categories.

My second example is my attempt at doing this recursively to support more levels. It works but I wonder how I can optimize it and add dashes similar to the first example.

```
# first example two levels deep, formatted properly with dashes
def build_choice_tree():
    categories = Category.query.get(1).children
    items = [(1, 'None')]
    for root in categories:
        items.append((root.id, root.name))
        if root.children:
            for subcat1 in root.children:
                items.append((subcat1.id, '- ' + subcat1.name))
                if subcat1.children:
                    for subcat2 in subcat1.children:
                        items.append((subcat2.id, '--' + subcat2.name))
    return items

# second example goes multiple levels, needs dashes
def build_choice_tree2():
    categories = Category.query.get(1).children
    items = []

    def loop(categories):
        for category in categories:
            items.append((category.id, category.name))
            if category.children:
                loop(category.children)
        return items
    result = loop(categories)
    return result
```

Comment: Do you need some spaces after the id? Or your meaning is each layer has the same length?

Comment: I need a space between the dash and name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter to store the number of dashes you want to add and multiply the dashes by that count. Also to make a function truly recursive you need to add the `return` statement.

```
def build_choice_tree2():
    categories = Category.query.get(1).children
    items = []
    count = 1

    def loop(categories, count):
        for category in categories:
            items.append((category.id,'-' * count, category.name))
            if category.children:
                count +=1
                return loop(category.children, count)
        return items

    return loop(categories, count)
```

Personally i would separate `loop` into a different method like this and avoid the inner `loop` method in build_choice_tree2. i'll also make `items` a default argument. since default arguments (mutable) are evaluated at function definition time, it will never get reset to it's original value of an empty list.

```
def loop(categories, count=1, items=[]):
    for category in categories:
        items.append((category.id,'-' * count, category.name))
        if category.children:
            count +=1
            return loop(category.children, count)
    return items
```

Comment: The second example without the inner function is perfect. I did not know a default list as argument would not be reset.

Comment: Here is a list of common python gotcha's that you might find helpful https://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make

Answer (score 1):

I change you example 2, and it will add dashes after the id, but it won't add spaces like your example 1.

```
# second example goes multiple levels, needs dashes
def build_choice_tree2():
    # For the convenience of the test, I changed `categories` to a list.
    categories = [{
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'root',
        'children': [{
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'child1',
            'children': [{
                'id': 3,
                'name': 'child2',
            }]
        }]
    }]
    items = []
    def loop(categories, depth):
        for category in categories:
            items.append((category['id'], '-' * depth + ' ' + category['name']))
            if category.get('children'):
                loop(category['children'], depth + 1)
        return items
    result = loop(categories, 0)
    print(result)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_choice_tree2()
```